#  lock and unlock settings like wifi,vibration,etc.. after clicking on button

Tags: android

How can I lock the current state of settings like wifi,gps,bluetooth,vibration,etc...after clicking on button1.and it should be unlock when button2 is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it that is possible, since if another app is running in the background or started it will get the control of the devices. Therefore I could be hard to know if it actually is locked.

Every app is added to the stack (of running apps), and the highest in the stack will probably have the rights to modify the devices of it's choice.